# Epplus auto select all sheet clone?

Tags: c#, epplus

In Epplus,i'm using copy worksheet

```
ExcelPackage package = (ExcelPackage)_workbook;
ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Copy(existingWorksheetName, newWorksheetName);
_workbook = package;
```

after exporting the file and open on Excel then all status sheet name is select
[Img all sheet status is select](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5fiN5.png)
Anyone know how to fix this?
Thanks!!!

Comment: You need to set the name of worksheet like worksheet .Name = "Some Name";

Comment: It's not work!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i using select in worksheet.That's working

```
        ExcelPackage package = (ExcelPackage)_workbook;
        if (package.Workbook.Worksheets.Count > 0)
            package.Workbook.Worksheets[1].Select();

        package.SaveAs(new FileInfo(path));
```